# Error loading feeds! Maybe because the connection failed or the blogger server did not respond to the request

Tags: cookies, blogger, feed, samesite

I try to change the Blogger theme but I am getting this error. I have unable and disabled cookies site and trying to solve but won't able to solve I am pasting the error SC and Thank your help.

[image: Error While loading mega Menu]

Console Error SC

[image: Console Error I am getting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blog is open to invited reader only, so you can't get feeds. to solve, you need to open the blog to public from:

**Settings** > **Basic** > **Blog Readers** > **Public**

Comment: Thanks, Buddy you save my lots of time GBU